# How to get all categories and users which subscribed on it?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

So, I tried to get all categories and check if current user is subscibed on one of each:

```
$subcategories = Category::with("user")->parentcategory($id)->get();
```

Where category model is:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->where("user_id", Auth::user()->id);
}
```

As you  can see I joins tables and set `->where("user_id", Auth::user()->id);` for join by condition.

According this I should to get all categories and joined table user, if condition is true(if user is subscribed).

After this I do:

```
$subcategories = $subcategories->map(function ($item) {
    $item->subscribed = $item->users->count();

    return $item;
});
```

This code checkes if current user is refers to category.
But it returns me wrong results.

Comment: There is one way how to do this: get all categories, get categories of user and to make difference of arrays. But I need to solve problem in question

Comment: What were the expected results and what did you have instead? Can you edit your question and explain the relations between your models?